# Recursive Python function not returning appropriate value

Tags: python, recursion

I've written a function to scroll a page that uses infinite scroll, using selenium I execute a script to scroll to the bottom, sleep for a few seconds (to give the page time to load more content), and check if the current scroll position is equal to the last scroll position (signaling that this is the true end of the page). In the segment below `end_of_scroll_region` never becomes true and the while loop runs indefinitely.

```
last_position = None
end_of_scroll_region = False
while not end_of_scroll_region:
     last_position, end_of_scroll_region = scroll_down_page(driver, last_position)
```

The `scroll_down_page` function actually executes the scripts to scroll and contains a recursive logic to retry the scrolling process to account for situations where the page needed more time to load by doing the scroll again with an attempt counter and incremented sleep time. But after countless debugging, I found that `end_of_scroll_region` becomes True but immediately goes back to False (assuming something is going within the callback).

```
def scroll_down_page(driver, last_position, num_seconds_to_load=0.5, scroll_attempt=0, max_attempts=5):
    end_of_scroll_region = False
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    sleep(num_seconds_to_load)
    curr_position = driver.execute_script("return window.pageYOffset;")
    if curr_position == last_position:
        if scroll_attempt == max_attempts:
            end_of_scroll_region = True
        else:
            scroll_down_page(driver, last_position, num_seconds_to_load+5, scroll_attempt + 1, max_attempts)
    last_position = curr_position
    return last_position, end_of_scroll_region
```

Comment: You're not capturing the return values from the recursive calls to `scroll_down_page`. Maybe a simple change such as: `last_position, end_of_scroll_region = scroll_down_page (...)`?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments I wasn't capturing the return values from the recursive call to `scroll_down_page`

```
def scroll_down_page(driver, last_position, num_seconds_to_load=0.5, scroll_attempt=0, max_attempts=5):
    end_of_scroll_region = False
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    sleep(num_seconds_to_load)
    curr_position = driver.execute_script("return window.pageYOffset;")
    if curr_position == last_position:
        if scroll_attempt == max_attempts:
            end_of_scroll_region = True
        else:
            #Solution
            last_position, end_of_scroll_region = scroll_down_page(driver, last_position, num_seconds_to_load+5, scroll_attempt + 1, max_attempts)
    last_position = curr_position
    return last_position, end_of_scroll_region
```